# Could I use metal buttons as a capacitive button for my arduino project?

Tags: arduino-uno

Could I use something like this as a capacitive button for my arduino project?

http://www.banggood.com/10pcs-25mm-Vintage-Round-Metal-Buttons-Craft-Scrapbooking-Sewing-Suit-Shirt-Button-p-1011485.html

If I connect it into something like this... http://www.banggood.com/MPR121-Capacitive-Touch-Sensor-Module-For-Raspberry-Pi-Arduino-p-969002.html

Would that make that button a capacitive button? Or am I totally barking up the wrong tree here?

Thanks :)

Comment: What type of wires are you going to use? Wearable design? You might be able to do capacitive button detect directly without the module. Use an analog pin and a 1-10 M resistor, and some software. http://tuomasnylund.fi/drupal6/content/capacitive-touch-sensing-avr-and-single-adc-pin

Comment: I don't know. When I designed a capacitive button the IC I used required a metal plane with a dielectric, and you had to touch the dielectric (so you created a capacitor between the metal plane and your finger). Maybe there are other capacitive button controllers that require direct metal...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would work.

The only thing to watch out for is that the buttons might be plastic with a thin layer of metal on top (Chemical vapor deposition).